# is it safe to pass an id of data selected from mysql database across pages and use it to fetch and display more data in php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a web page where after connecting to and selecting courses from the database, the courses are displayed with a link to view each course as below:

```
<div class="col-md-4">

    //query db action and assign the query to $result
    $result = $dbcon->query($query);

    if($result -> num_rows > 0){

        //If courses are available(rows > 0), fetch and display them

        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){

            echo '<h2>'.$row->course_title.'</h2';

            echo '<p>'.$row->course_description.'</p>';

            echo '<a href="view.php?action=view&t='. $row->course_id.'">View Course</a>';
        }
    }

</div>
```

And this is the code for *view.php* page:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "view"){

    //Assign var $id to the id from the _GET array
    $id = $_GET['t'];

    //Use the $id to fetch course details from the database
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE course_id = '$id'");

    //Query the db action
    $result = $db_connect->query($query);

    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($result && $rows > 0){

        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){

            echo '<div class="col-md-10">';

                echo '<h1>'.$row->course_title.'</h1>';

                echo '<p>'.$row->course_description.'</p>';

                echo '<div class="col-md-6"><span class="inline-elm">'.$row->course_subject.'</div>';

                echo '<div class="col-md-6"><span>'.$row->course_level.'</p></div>'</div>';
         }
     }
}
```

My problem is that I'm not sure whether this is proper and of course, safe to do or there is a safer/proper way to do it. Will really appreciate your answers. Thanks

Comment: your code isn't safe; use a prepared statement

Comment: How do I use prepared statements here?

Comment: Can you use user input in your query? sure, but the way you are doing it now *is* unsafe. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to get a better idea of how to protect yourself

Comment: Thanks for the link, it really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine to pass ids inside urls, but they should be handled like any other data, ie properly sanitized, validated and escaped. A prepared statement is a good way to do this. At the very least, here, since you expect an int, you can do:

```
$id = intval($_GET['t']);
```

Note that prepared statements do not protect against XSS vulnerabilities which would occur if doing "echo $id" without wrapping it in htmlspecialchars. Input sanitization is always nice, if it's an int, stick an intval on it! You never know...